# Can one use scipy sparse matrices in args of scipy.optimize.fmin_cg?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am minimizing a function with scipy.optimize.fmin_cg. In "args" one can supply additional fixed parameters that are needed to completely specify the functions and it's derivative. I want to use a sparse representation, scipy.sparse.csr_matrix, of some arguments. I have the same function coded both with the sparse matrix as well as a dense ndarray. I have noticed differences in the solution.

Does anyone know whether scipy.optimize.fmin_cg accepts sparse matrices in "args"?

Thanks!

Comment: In most (if not all) of those `scipy.optimize` functions, `args` variables are passed intact to your function.  So if there is a difference in behavior or results, the cause must lie in your own code.  Have you tested your function(s) with both styles of input? (direct call, not via `fmin_cg`).